# Can't put a single quote before the year in NSDateFormatter

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to format my date as follows:

```
Mon, Apr 14 '09
```

The `dateFormat` I'm setting for my `NSDateFormatter` is `EEE, MMM dd 'yy` but it shows:

```
Mon, Apr 14 'yy
```

If I take out the single quote before the year, I get the last two digits of the year but it's not obvious that it's the year because the single quote is gone. Help?

I've also tried putting `'''`, `'\''`, and `'\'''` before 'yy' but it doesn't work, although the last two produced `'yy` and `''09`

Comment: do you want it to display to UILabel?

Comment: Then remove ' from formater. Get the date, convert it into string then insert ' mark in the string

Comment: ^LOL that's a really inelegant hack... that works. ;) Still waiting for a better solution though.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From [http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date%5fFormat%5fPatterns):

> In patterns, two single quotes represents a literal single quote, …

In your case:

```
 [formatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, MMM dd ''yy"];
```

Comment: I imagine those guys writing the unicode standards: "Dude, what if they want a quote in their date formatter?" "Yeah, well they'll first think to escape characters with a backslash, should we go for backslash here too?" "Nope, let's use another quote. And we'll state that in a 2 line paragraph in a 9-chapter document. That'll do it."